# toggle select add and remove

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm displaying a product catalog, listing available products and all product related rateplans. Each rateplan has toggle button to add the product + rateplan to the order.

these are the functions to add remove the items to the order in the component.ts file:

```
 addrateplan(rateplan, product) {
    this.selectedRateplans = this.selectedRateplans.concat(rateplan);
    this.selectedProducts = this.selectedProducts.concat(product);
    this.snackBar.open(rateplan.name + ' added', 'close', {
        duration: 3000,
    });
  }
  removerateplan(rateplan, i) {
    this.selectedRateplans.splice(i, 1);
    this.snackBar.open(rateplan.name + ' removed', 'close', {
        duration: 3000,
    });
  }

  toggleChange(event) {
    console.log(event);
  }
```

this is the section from .html where I display selected rateplans

```
<table *ngIf="selectedRateplans">
  <tr *ngFor="let rateplan of selectedRateplans; let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i">
    <td><button mat-button color="warn" (click)="removerateplan(rateplan, i)">remove</button></td><td>{{ rateplan.name }}</td><td>{{ rateplan.status }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

this is the button displayed for each rateplan to add products and rateplans:

```
 <mat-button-toggle-group #group="matButtonToggleGroup" multiple (change)="toggleChange($event.value)">
                  <mat-button-toggle value="rateplan" #left>
                    <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
                  </mat-button-toggle>
                </mat-button-toggle-group>
    // I used to have a normal button and call (click)="addrateplan(rateplan, element) to add rateplans
```

I do have three issues:
 1. fixed - I can't remove rateplans (I think there is something wrong with how I'm using splice) --> see update remove section in component.ts

2. I want to change for usability reasons the former add button with a toggle button.
3. It would be great if the toggle button changes from + (product/rateplan not added yet --> clicking will add) to - (product added --> clicking will remove rateplan)

this is an example for the product / rateplan json format:

```
{
    "products": [{
            "id": "8adce42168831a9501688f75d9102aaa",
            "sku": "SKU-00001111",
            "name": "test 2",
            "description": "",
            "category": "Base Products",
            "effectiveStartDate": "2010-01-27",
            "effectiveEndDate": "2100-01-27",
            "allowFeatureChanges": false,
            "StoreAppID__c": null,
            "Prerequisites__c": null,
            "Partner_Account_ID__c": null,
            "productRatePlans": [{
                    "id": "8adc8f9968830c1c01688f76d42c4509",
                    "status": "Active",
                    "name": "plan 3",
                    "description": "",
                    "effectiveStartDate": "2010-01-27",
                    "effectiveEndDate": "2100-01-27",
                    "IsTrialRatePlan__c": "False",
                    "mainIVK__c": null,
                    "IVK__c": null,
                    "IVKtype__c": null,
                    "PriceType__c": "SW",
                    "VBLO__c": null,
                    "PriceCode__c": "K",
                    "CurrencyOfBasePrice__c": "EUR",
                    "BasePrice__c": null,
                    "productRatePlanCharges": [{
                        "id": "8adce42168831a9501688f7791122afd",
                        "name": "New Component",
                        "type": "OneTime",
                        "model": "PerUnit",
                        "uom": "MB",
                        "pricingSummary": [
                            "USD100/MB"
                        ],
                        "pricing": [{
                            "currency": "USD",
                            "price": 100,
                            "tiers": null,
                            "includedUnits": null,
                            "overagePrice": null,
                            "discountPercentage": null,
                            "discountAmount": null
                        }],
                        "defaultQuantity": 1,
                        "applyDiscountTo": null,
                        "discountLevel": null,
                        "discountClass": null,
                        "productDiscountApplyDetails": [],
                        "endDateCondition": "One_Time",
                        "upToPeriods": null,
                        "upToPeriodsType": null,
                        "billingDay": null,
                        "listPriceBase": null,
                        "billingTiming": null,
                        "billingPeriod": null,
                        "billingPeriodAlignment": null,
                        "specificBillingPeriod": null,
                        "smoothingModel": null,
                        "numberOfPeriods": null,
                        "overageCalculationOption": null,
                        "overageUnusedUnitsCreditOption": null,
                        "unusedIncludedUnitPrice": null,
                        "usageRecordRatingOption": null,
                        "priceChangeOption": null,
                        "priceIncreasePercentage": null,
                        "useTenantDefaultForPriceChange": null,
                        "taxable": false,
                        "taxCode": "",
                        "taxMode": "TaxExclusive",
                        "triggerEvent": "ContractEffective",
                        "description": "",
                        "revRecCode": null,
                        "revRecTriggerCondition": null,
                        "revenueRecognitionRuleName": "Recognize upon invoicing",
                        "useDiscountSpecificAccountingCode": null,
                        "financeInformation": {
                            "deferredRevenueAccountingCode": "Professional Services Revenue",
                            "deferredRevenueAccountingCodeType": "SalesRevenue",
                            "recognizedRevenueAccountingCode": "Professional Services Revenue",
                            "recognizedRevenueAccountingCodeType": "SalesRevenue"
                        }
                    }]
                },
                {
                    "id": "8adce42168831a9501688f767c252aae",
                    "status": "Active",
                    "name": "plan 2",
                    "description": "",
                    "effectiveStartDate": "2010-01-27",
                    "effectiveEndDate": "2100-01-27",
                    "IsTrialRatePlan__c": "False",
                    "mainIVK__c": null,
                    "IVK__c": null,
                    "IVKtype__c": null,
                    "PriceType__c": "SW",
                    "VBLO__c": null,
                    "PriceCode__c": "K",
                    "CurrencyOfBasePrice__c": "EUR",
                    "BasePrice__c": null,
                    "productRatePlanCharges": [{
                        "id": "8adce42168831a9501688f774d0c2ab0",
                        "name": "New Component",
                        "type": "OneTime",
                        "model": "FlatFee",
                        "uom": null,
                        "pricingSummary": [
                            "USD1000"
                        ],
                        "pricing": [{
                            "currency": "USD",
                            "price": 1000,
                            "tiers": null,
                            "includedUnits": null,
                            "overagePrice": null,
                            "discountPercentage": null,
                            "discountAmount": null
                        }],
                        "defaultQuantity": null,
                        "applyDiscountTo": null,
                        "discountLevel": null,
                        "discountClass": null,
                        "productDiscountApplyDetails": [],
                        "endDateCondition": "One_Time",
                        "upToPeriods": null,
                        "upToPeriodsType": null,
                        "billingDay": null,
                        "listPriceBase": null,
                        "billingTiming": null,
                        "billingPeriod": null,
                        "billingPeriodAlignment": null,
                        "specificBillingPeriod": null,
                        "smoothingModel": null,
                        "numberOfPeriods": null,
                        "overageCalculationOption": null,
                        "overageUnusedUnitsCreditOption": null,
                        "unusedIncludedUnitPrice": null,
                        "usageRecordRatingOption": null,
                        "priceChangeOption": null,
                        "priceIncreasePercentage": null,
                        "useTenantDefaultForPriceChange": null,
                        "taxable": false,
                        "taxCode": "",
                        "taxMode": "TaxExclusive",
                        "triggerEvent": "ContractEffective",
                        "description": "",
                        "revRecCode": null,
                        "revRecTriggerCondition": null,
                        "revenueRecognitionRuleName": "Recognize upon invoicing",
                        "useDiscountSpecificAccountingCode": null,
                        "financeInformation": {
                            "deferredRevenueAccountingCode": "Professional Services Revenue",
                            "deferredRevenueAccountingCodeType": "SalesRevenue",
                            "recognizedRevenueAccountingCode": "Professional Services Revenue",
                            "recognizedRevenueAccountingCodeType": "SalesRevenue"
                        }
                    }]
                },
                {
                    "id": "8adc8f9968830c1c01688f762aac4506",
                    "status": "Active",
                    "name": "test",
                    "description": "",
                    "effectiveStartDate": "2010-09-05",
                    "effectiveEndDate": "2100-01-27",
                    "IsTrialRatePlan__c": "False",
                    "mainIVK__c": null,
                    "IVK__c": null,
                    "IVKtype__c": null,
                    "PriceType__c": "SW",
                    "VBLO__c": null,
                    "PriceCode__c": "K",
                    "CurrencyOfBasePrice__c": "EUR",
                    "BasePrice__c": null,
                    "productRatePlanCharges": [{
                        "id": "8adc8f9968830c1c01688f771bf4450b",
                        "name": "one time",
                        "type": "OneTime",
                        "model": "FlatFee",
                        "uom": null,
                        "pricingSummary": [
                            "USD15"
                        ],
                        "pricing": [{
                            "currency": "USD",
                            "price": 15,
                            "tiers": null,
                            "includedUnits": null,
                            "overagePrice": null,
                            "discountPercentage": null,
                            "discountAmount": null
                        }],
                        "defaultQuantity": null,
                        "applyDiscountTo": null,
                        "discountLevel": null,
                        "discountClass": null,
                        "productDiscountApplyDetails": [],
                        "endDateCondition": "One_Time",
                        "upToPeriods": null,
                        "upToPeriodsType": null,
                        "billingDay": null,
                        "listPriceBase": null,
                        "billingTiming": null,
                        "billingPeriod": null,
                        "billingPeriodAlignment": null,
                        "specificBillingPeriod": null,
                        "smoothingModel": null,
                        "numberOfPeriods": null,
                        "overageCalculationOption": null,
                        "overageUnusedUnitsCreditOption": null,
                        "unusedIncludedUnitPrice": null,
                        "usageRecordRatingOption": null,
                        "priceChangeOption": null,
                        "priceIncreasePercentage": null,
                        "useTenantDefaultForPriceChange": null,
                        "taxable": false,
                        "taxCode": "",
                        "taxMode": "TaxExclusive",
                        "triggerEvent": "ContractEffective",
                        "description": "",
                        "revRecCode": null,
                        "revRecTriggerCondition": null,
                        "revenueRecognitionRuleName": "Recognize upon invoicing",
                        "useDiscountSpecificAccountingCode": null,
                        "financeInformation": {
                            "deferredRevenueAccountingCode": "Professional Services Revenue",
                            "deferredRevenueAccountingCodeType": "SalesRevenue",
                            "recognizedRevenueAccountingCode": "Professional Services Revenue",
                            "recognizedRevenueAccountingCodeType": "SalesRevenue"
                        }
                    }]
                }
            ],
            "productFeatures": []
        },
        {
            "id": "8adc8f9968830c1c01688a5cbdc7786a",
            "sku": "SKU-00001110",
            "name": "Malte Test",
            "description": "",
            "category": "Base Products",
            "effectiveStartDate": "2017-09-12",
            "effectiveEndDate": "2090-09-12",
            "allowFeatureChanges": false,
            "StoreAppID__c": null,
            "Prerequisites__c": null,
            "Partner_Account_ID__c": null,
            "productRatePlans": [{
                    "id": "8adce42168831a9501688a7409736692",
                    "status": "Active",
                    "name": "rateplan 2",
                    "description": "",
                    "effectiveStartDate": "2018-01-03",
                    "effectiveEndDate": "2025-01-03",
                    "IsTrialRatePlan__c": "False",
                    "mainIVK__c": null,
                    "IVK__c": null,
                    "IVKtype__c": null,
                    "PriceType__c": "SW",
                    "VBLO__c": null,
                    "PriceCode__c": "K",
                    "CurrencyOfBasePrice__c": "EUR",
                    "BasePrice__c": null,
                    "productRatePlanCharges": [{
                        "id": "8adce42168831a9501688a7451576694",
                        "name": "one time",
                        "type": "OneTime",
                        "model": "FlatFee",
                        "uom": null,
                        "pricingSummary": [
                            "USD100"
                        ],
                        "pricing": [{
                            "currency": "USD",
                            "price": 100,
                            "tiers": null,
                            "includedUnits": null,
                            "overagePrice": null,
                            "discountPercentage": null,
                            "discountAmount": null
                        }],
                        "defaultQuantity": null,
                        "applyDiscountTo": null,
                        "discountLevel": null,
                        "discountClass": null,
                        "productDiscountApplyDetails": [],
                        "endDateCondition": "One_Time",
                        "upToPeriods": null,
                        "upToPeriodsType": null,
                        "billingDay": null,
                        "listPriceBase": null,
                        "billingTiming": null,
                        "billingPeriod": null,
                        "billingPeriodAlignment": null,
                        "specificBillingPeriod": null,
                        "smoothingModel": null,
                        "numberOfPeriods": null,
                        "overageCalculationOption": null,
                        "overageUnusedUnitsCreditOption": null,
                        "unusedIncludedUnitPrice": null,
                        "usageRecordRatingOption": null,
                        "priceChangeOption": null,
                        "priceIncreasePercentage": null,
                        "useTenantDefaultForPriceChange": null,
                        "taxable": false,
                        "taxCode": "",
                        "taxMode": "TaxExclusive",
                        "triggerEvent": "ContractEffective",
                        "description": "",
                        "revRecCode": null,
                        "revRecTriggerCondition": null,
                        "revenueRecognitionRuleName": "Recognize upon invoicing",
                        "useDiscountSpecificAccountingCode": null,
                        "financeInformation": {
                            "deferredRevenueAccountingCode": "Professional Services Revenue",
                            "deferredRevenueAccountingCodeType": "SalesRevenue",
                            "recognizedRevenueAccountingCode": "Professional Services Revenue",
                            "recognizedRevenueAccountingCodeType": "SalesRevenue"
                        }
                    }]
                },
                {
                    "id": "8adc8f9968830c1c01688a5db088786c",
                    "status": "Active",
                    "name": "Malte rateplan",
                    "description": "",
                    "effectiveStartDate": "2017-09-12",
                    "effectiveEndDate": "2090-09-12",
                    "IsTrialRatePlan__c": "False",
                    "mainIVK__c": null,
                    "IVK__c": null,
                    "IVKtype__c": null,
                    "PriceType__c": "SW",
                    "VBLO__c": null,
                    "PriceCode__c": "K",
                    "CurrencyOfBasePrice__c": "EUR",
                    "BasePrice__c": null,
                    "productRatePlanCharges": [{
                            "id": "8adc8f9968830c1c01688a5fa31578bd",
                            "name": "usage",
                            "type": "Usage",
                            "model": "Tiered",
                            "uom": "Shared Studies",
                            "pricingSummary": [
                                "1 to 10 Shared Studies: USD0 flat fee;  11 to 20 Shared Studies: USD10/Shared Studies;  21 to 100 Shared Studies: USD5/Shared Studies"
                            ],
                            "pricing": [{
                                "currency": "USD",
                                "price": null,
                                "tiers": [{
                                        "tier": 1,
                                        "startingUnit": 1,
                                        "endingUnit": 10,
                                        "price": 0,
                                        "priceFormat": "FlatFee"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "tier": 2,
                                        "startingUnit": 11,
                                        "endingUnit": 20,
                                        "price": 10,
                                        "priceFormat": "PerUnit"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "tier": 3,
                                        "startingUnit": 21,
                                        "endingUnit": 100,
                                        "price": 5,
                                        "priceFormat": "PerUnit"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "includedUnits": null,
                                "overagePrice": null,
                                "discountPercentage": null,
                                "discountAmount": null
                            }],
                            "defaultQuantity": null,
                            "applyDiscountTo": null,
                            "discountLevel": null,
                            "discountClass": null,
                            "productDiscountApplyDetails": [],
                            "endDateCondition": "Subscription_End",
                            "upToPeriods": null,
                            "upToPeriodsType": null,
                            "billingDay": "DefaultFromCustomer",
                            "listPriceBase": null,
                            "billingTiming": null,
                            "billingPeriod": "Month",
                            "billingPeriodAlignment": "AlignToCharge",
                            "specificBillingPeriod": null,
                            "smoothingModel": null,
                            "numberOfPeriods": null,
                            "overageCalculationOption": null,
                            "overageUnusedUnitsCreditOption": null,
                            "unusedIncludedUnitPrice": null,
                            "usageRecordRatingOption": "EndOfBillingPeriod",
                            "priceChangeOption": null,
                            "priceIncreasePercentage": null,
                            "useTenantDefaultForPriceChange": null,
                            "taxable": false,
                            "taxCode": "",
                            "taxMode": "TaxExclusive",
                            "triggerEvent": "ContractEffective",
                            "description": "",
                            "revRecCode": null,
                            "revRecTriggerCondition": null,
                            "revenueRecognitionRuleName": "Recognize upon invoicing",
                            "useDiscountSpecificAccountingCode": null,
                            "financeInformation": {
                                "deferredRevenueAccountingCode": "Professional Services Revenue",
                                "deferredRevenueAccountingCodeType": "SalesRevenue",
                                "recognizedRevenueAccountingCode": "Professional Services Revenue",
                                "recognizedRevenueAccountingCodeType": "SalesRevenue"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "8adce42168831a9501688a5e75f16501",
                            "name": "monthly",
                            "type": "Recurring",
                            "model": "FlatFee",
                            "uom": null,
                            "pricingSummary": [
                                "USD50"
                            ],
                            "pricing": [{
                                "currency": "USD",
                                "price": 50,
                                "tiers": null,
                                "includedUnits": null,
                                "overagePrice": null,
                                "discountPercentage": null,
                                "discountAmount": null
                            }],
                            "defaultQuantity": null,
                            "applyDiscountTo": null,
                            "discountLevel": null,
                            "discountClass": null,
                            "productDiscountApplyDetails": [],
                            "endDateCondition": "Subscription_End",
                            "upToPeriods": null,
                            "upToPeriodsType": null,
                            "billingDay": "DefaultFromCustomer",
                            "listPriceBase": "Per_Billing_Period",
                            "billingTiming": "IN_ADVANCE",
                            "billingPeriod": "Month",
                            "billingPeriodAlignment": "AlignToCharge",
                            "specificBillingPeriod": null,
                            "smoothingModel": null,
                            "numberOfPeriods": null,
                            "overageCalculationOption": null,
                            "overageUnusedUnitsCreditOption": null,
                            "unusedIncludedUnitPrice": null,
                            "usageRecordRatingOption": null,
                            "priceChangeOption": null,
                            "priceIncreasePercentage": null,
                            "useTenantDefaultForPriceChange": null,
                            "taxable": false,
                            "taxCode": "",
                            "taxMode": "TaxExclusive",
                            "triggerEvent": "ContractEffective",
                            "description": "",
                            "revRecCode": null,
                            "revRecTriggerCondition": null,
                            "revenueRecognitionRuleName": "Recognize upon invoicing",
                            "useDiscountSpecificAccountingCode": null,
                            "financeInformation": {
                                "deferredRevenueAccountingCode": "Professional Services Revenue",
                                "deferredRevenueAccountingCodeType": "SalesRevenue",
                                "recognizedRevenueAccountingCode": "Professional Services Revenue",
                                "recognizedRevenueAccountingCodeType": "SalesRevenue"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "8adc8f9968830c1c01688a5e0770786e",
                            "name": "sign up",
                            "type": "OneTime",
                            "model": "FlatFee",
                            "uom": null,
                            "pricingSummary": [
                                "USD100"
                            ],
                            "pricing": [{
                                "currency": "USD",
                                "price": 100,
                                "tiers": null,
                                "includedUnits": null,
                                "overagePrice": null,
                                "discountPercentage": null,
                                "discountAmount": null
                            }],
                            "defaultQuantity": null,
                            "applyDiscountTo": null,
                            "discountLevel": null,
                            "discountClass": null,
                            "productDiscountApplyDetails": [],
                            "endDateCondition": "One_Time",
                            "upToPeriods": null,
                            "upToPeriodsType": null,
                            "billingDay": null,
                            "listPriceBase": null,
                            "billingTiming": null,
                            "billingPeriod": null,
                            "billingPeriodAlignment": null,
                            "specificBillingPeriod": null,
                            "smoothingModel": null,
                            "numberOfPeriods": null,
                            "overageCalculationOption": null,
                            "overageUnusedUnitsCreditOption": null,
                            "unusedIncludedUnitPrice": null,
                            "usageRecordRatingOption": null,
                            "priceChangeOption": null,
                            "priceIncreasePercentage": null,
                            "useTenantDefaultForPriceChange": null,
                            "taxable": false,
                            "taxCode": "",
                            "taxMode": "TaxExclusive",
                            "triggerEvent": "ContractEffective",
                            "description": "",
                            "revRecCode": null,
                            "revRecTriggerCondition": null,
                            "revenueRecognitionRuleName": "Recognize upon invoicing",
                            "useDiscountSpecificAccountingCode": null,
                            "financeInformation": {
                                "deferredRevenueAccountingCode": "Professional Services Revenue",
                                "deferredRevenueAccountingCodeType": "SalesRevenue",
                                "recognizedRevenueAccountingCode": "Professional Services Revenue",
                                "recognizedRevenueAccountingCodeType": "SalesRevenue"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "productFeatures": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your splice function is not correct.
Syntax of splice

```
array.splice(index, howmany, item1, ....., itemX)
```

you need to give an index, then the number of items you want to replace from that index, then the items you want to replace with. Have a look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp)

you are already passing the index i to removerateplan() method. No need of `this.selectedRateplans.indexOf(i)` this.

your updated function will be,

```
removerateplan(rateplan, i) {
    this.selectedRateplans = this.selectedRateplans.splice(i, 1);
    this.snackBar.open(rateplan.name + ' removed', 'close', {
        duration: 3000,
    });
  }
```

Comment: I changed the function as you suggested but now it's not deleting the first item and ich there are more than 2 items it removes all items except for the first one when removing some item